# How to change the text of yes/no buttons in JavaFX 8 Alert dialogs

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

I have this code snippet:

```
Alert alert = 
        new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, 
            "The format for dates is year.month.day. " +
            "For example, today is " + todayToString() + ".",
             ButtonType.OK, 
             ButtonType.CANCEL);
alert.setTitle("Date format warning");
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
    formatGotIt = true;
}
```

Above, I request two buttons titled "Yes" and "No." However, I wish to change them both.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can define your own button types. In this example the buttons' text is `foo` and `bar`:

```
ButtonType foo = new ButtonType("foo", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
ButtonType bar = new ButtonType("bar", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING,
        "The format for dates is year.month.day. "
        + "For example, today is " + todayToString() + ".",
        foo,
        bar);

alert.setTitle("Date format warning");
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

if (result.orElse(bar) == foo) {
    formatGotIt = true;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
((Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK)).setText("Not OK Anymore");
((Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CANCEL)).setText("Not Cancel Anymore");
```

Comment: Actually, I find this might be useful to someone. Especially in case of JavaFx dialog like Alert.  Example: Alert errorAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);

Comment: its Very Relevant, solved my issue. Just remember that 'dialog' might also be a "Alert" object.